# Pyinstaller failed to install, github

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

I failed to install Pyinstaller while following the [github guide](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller), it freezes in this step :

```
Installed /home/g573072/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyinstaller-4.0.dev0+7a7eb11a7b-py3.7.egg
Processing dependencies for pyinstaller==4.0.dev0+7a7eb11a7b
Searching for altgraph
Reading https://pypi.org/simple/altgraph/
```

and then I get this error:

```
Download error on https://pypi.org/simple/altgraph/: [Errno 110] Connection timed out -- Some packages may not be found!
Couldn't find index page for 'altgraph' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading https://pypi.org/simple/
Download error on https://pypi.org/simple/: [Errno 110] Connection timed out -- Some packages may not be found!
No local packages or working download links found for altgraph
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('altgraph')
```

I'm not working behind a proxy and I don't understand why it won't work

Comment: From my understanding, it looks like a connection problem. If you still find the error try to build it from the [source](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller#untested-platforms) locally.

Comment: i tried and it failed to download, i got this error error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('altgraph')

Comment: Just grab the source from GitHub and run `python setup.py install` in the root directory.

Comment: I tried your solution but the problem is with Reading https://pypi.org/simple/altgraph
it can't read it

Comment: Have you tried to `pip install altgraph-0.17-py2.py3-none-any.whl`?